# how can I enable the virtual keyboard without a touchscreen? (win7)

Tags: delphi, touch, delphi-xe3

This might sound like a silly question but how can I enable the virtual keyboard in a delphi application when my development computer has no touchscreen?  I want to debug some of how the automatic touch screen (XE3) appears automatically.

I want to have the application think there is a touch screen so it will act as it does on a touch screen computer.

Answer (score 0):

Well as I have mentioned in [another reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741527/gesture-events-are-not-emulate-by-chrome/12852184#12852184) I recommend [Multitouch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com) which ignoring the visual studio and Silverlight specific bits can be set up like in this [easier to use guide](http://michaelsync.net/2010/04/06/step-by-step-tutorial-installing-multi-touch-simulator-for-silverlight-phone-7) else use the youtube video on their site. MTVista will install a virtual touch device (with 255 touches) and when running and being used correctly it will generate native touch messages which is the closest you can do to testing making it think it has touch, without a touch screen, as per your comment in another reply.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I did try it but started having problems getting the instructions to work.  Upon reading other people's problems, I decided not to continue in this direction.