# Debugging TouchInput WPF application on a computer without TouchInput

Tags: c#, wpf, input, touch, emulation

I need to add support TouchInput in my app. (For example, to scale the image or scroll ScrollViewer)
But the test is not on anything. Is there any idea how to emulate TouchInput?
Maybe use it as a connected Android tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming General WPF touch as opposed to Surface SDK use Multitouch Vista:

[See how to at a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12852184/537198)